# how to quote string for queries in perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, perl-module

I need to match large strings with the fields of a column in mysqlDB. something like

**%ERROR-kkl_ub{}: (from YAMios): Destination (name = sdasdays.s0sda.rindasdth.sbo98.sbssdao_sad) is not registered.**

it contains a lot of special characters, i cannot try and do a \ for each of them as there will be hundreds of unique signatures.

need help...

Comment: Are you doing a LIKE or REGEXP search inside MySQL?

Comment: tried both, regex errored out saying "An expression of non-boo
lean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'regex'."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In perl, us literal quotes, with single quote characters, or the q operator, which was designed for quoting literal strings which may have the normal quote characters often.  q (and qq for interpolated strings) allows for the next character to be the bounding quote character (similar to the m and s regular expression operators).

```
my $var1 = 'this is a "literal" string';
my $var2 = "this is an \"interpolated\" string";
my $var3 = q/this is a "literal" 'string'/;
my $var4 = q{another literal string};
my $var5 = qq/interpolated string, previous one was '$var2'/;
```

If you are worried about getting the strings into SQL queries (I admit I found your wording slightly confusing), use bound variables.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? OR string_field = ?');
my $rv = $sth->execute(1425, $var5);
```

See the DBI perldoc for more info.

Comment: what does this do??
        $sth->execute(1425, $var5);

i mean what does the 1425 stand for????

Comment: `$sth->execute(1425, $var5);` 1425 will be bond to `id` and $var5 to `string_field=$var5` overall your prepare statement at execution time will be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id =1425  OR string_field = $var5` 
this is concept of binding parameters.http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.617/DBI.pm